# How to specify the path to lib in gcc

Tags: gcc, boost, g++, ld

I have the problem about linking libraries.

"見つかりません" means "Not found"

1. edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   ```
   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myname/.local/boost/lib" g++ main.cc -lboost_serialization
   /home/myname/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: -lboost_serialization が見つかりません
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```
2. edit LIBRARY_PATH

   ```
   $ LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myname/.local/boost/lib" g++ main.cc -lboost_serialization
   /home/myname/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: -lboost_serialization が見つかりません
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```
3. adding the -L option (successfully compiled)

   ```
   $ g++ main.cc -lboost_serialization -L "/home/myname/.local/boost/lib"
   $
   ```

Indeed I have successfully compiled my program with the -L option.
But I want to compile without this (like 1 or 2, not 3).

In this case, what do I have to check or modify in my environmental variables?

note: my gcc is 5.3.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.3.0).

Comment: -L is the way to specify library search path for gcc used by about 100% of developers. Why do you want something else?

Comment: thanks for reply! 
This program is built by Make.
And this program is ran on some machines.
So I don't want to edit Makefile and want to edit environment variables.